# Flow variable not being set via LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, visual-workflow

I have a custom lookup component which needs to set my `referringAccountId` variable in my screen flow. I have created the variable, setup the LWC component to assign the variable. To test I have also displayed the variable on the screen so I can determine if the variable has been set.

When my lookup is selected my `handleSelectionChange` is fired, which I have verified is working as the console log messages are shown. But the display text is never changed.

Can someone explain what I am missing?

LWC/Flow setup:
[image: image of flow]

LWC meta:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <apiVersion>58.0</apiVersion>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
    <masterLabel>Account Lookup</masterLabel>
    <targets>
      <target>lightning__FlowScreen</target>
    </targets>
  <targetConfigs>
    <targetConfig targets="lightning__FlowScreen">
        <property name="referringAccountId" type="String" role="outputOnly"/>
    </targetConfig>
</targetConfigs>
</LightningComponentBundle>
```

JS:

```
import { LightningElement, wire, api } from 'lwc';
import { FlowAttributeChangeEvent } from 'lightning/flowSupport';
import accountSearch from '@salesforce/apex/LookupController.accountSearch';

export default class AddReferringAccountLeadScreenFlow extends LightningElement {
    @api referringAccountId;

    handleSearch(event) {
        const lookupElement = event.target;

        accountSearch(event.detail)
            .then(results => {
                lookupElement.setSearchResults(results);
            })
            .catch(error => {
                // error message goes here
            });
    }

    handleSelectionChange(event) {
        const selectedIds = event.detail;
        console.log('** selected ID: ' + selectedIds[0]);
        console.log('** referringAccountId BEFORE:', this.referringAccountId);
        // const attributeChangeEvent = new FlowAttributeChangeEvent('referringAccountId', selectedIds[0]);
        const attributeChangeEvent = new FlowAttributeChangeEvent('referringAccountId', '001TA000002VtyNYAS');
        this.dispatchEvent(attributeChangeEvent);  

        console.log('** referringAccountId AFTER:', this.referringAccountId);
    }

}
```

Comment: You need the LWC to write to its own "output" API property (which means you must make it a getter/setter based property, otherwise it is immutable) and then raise the flow attribute change event.

Comment: Thanks @PhilW, this did the trick. Can you turn this into an answer please?

Answer (score 0):

To allow an LWC to communicate a property value back to a flow, not only do you need to dispatch a `FlowAttributeChangeEvent` but you must **first** set the property to the value you want to return.

The property itself must be an `@api` one, with the required role defined where it is declared in the target properties.

Note, however, that LWC API properties are immutable, once set, so cannot be written to by the LWC itself. This is resolved by turning the property into one that is defined using setter and getter methods.